Marginal effects at User-Specified Values with slopes function
I am having trouble with estimating the marginal effects at User-Specified Values with the slope function of the marginaleffects package
Let's imagine I want to predict body_mass_g with the palmer penguins dataset
library(marginaleffects)

dat <- read.csv(
 "https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/palmerpenguins/penguins.csv")


This is my function. I want to set flipper_length at 180 and bill_length_mm  at either 39 and 40.
mod.lm <- lm(body_mass_g ~ bill_length_mm + flipper_length_mm + 
                           species, data = dat)

slopes(
  mod.lm,
  newdata = datagrid(
    flipper_length_mm = 180,
    bill_length_mm = c(39,40)))



I know something is wrong since the estimate for all of the predictors is the same, whether the value for bill_length_mm is set at 39 or 40.
I've tried running a similar model with a glm binary outcome variable and it works as intended.
dat$large_penguin <- ifelse(dat$body_mass_g > 
    median(dat$body_mass_g, na.rm = TRUE), 1, 0)

mod <- glm(large_penguin ~ bill_length_mm + flipper_length_mm + 
                           species, data = dat, family = binomial)

slopes(
  mod,
  newdata = datagrid(
    flipper_length_mm = 180,
    bill_length_mm = c(39,40)))


Why is the lm model not performing as intended while the glm one does?

In a linear model, the marginal effects of a predictor are constant because the relationship between the predictor and the outcome is assumed to be linear. Therefore, no matter which value of bill_length_mm you use, the estimated slopes (i.e., marginal effects) will be the same. This is because the partial derivative of the outcome with respect to bill_length_mm is constant, as it does not depend on the values of bill_length_mm in a linear model.
